# General protection fault in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, general-protection-fault

Node crashed with a [General Protection Fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault). From syslog:

```
Mar 12 23:51:01 ip-10-159-31-166 kernel: [136874.501802] node[28987] general protection ip:8902a8 sp:7fffe8326820 error:0 in node[400000+786000]
```

I'm assuming Node itself is the cause as JS is memory managed - let me know if that's incorrect.

```
> process.version
'v0.8.19'
```

Is there a known issue in node 0.8.19 that causes this?

How can I make node not crash?

Comment: Does it always crash or does it crash on certain code? If so, could you pinpoint what the code is on which it crashes?

Comment: @robertklep The app had been crashing once every few days. Alas my app logs weren't timestamped (planningto fix this now). I recalled something re: a memory issue in 0.8 (I remember some controversy as it included an API change mid release) so I've upgraded to 0.10 already.

Comment: A GPF can be anything, from SIGSEGV to something more serious. Lets hope 0.10.0 solves your issue :)